# Web application framework in java with eclipse plugin

Tags: java, frameworks

I would like to start off with a web application developed using a framework, I specifically want to code using Java and also need a plugin in eclipse so that it is easy to debug and deploy.

I have gone through a couple of web sites and found ZK, extjs Vaadin which can be used for the framework development. But I would like more input on this. Whether these are the best frameworks or is there some thing else that will be useful.

Thanks,
Bhavya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) is a great framework with [good eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/eclipse/). GWT is my preference

Answer (score 1):

[JBoss SEAM](http://seamframework.org/) framework. Install the [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) package (also available in Eclipse MarketPlace). It allows you to integrate JSF, JPA with a Seam Framework. JSF & JPA are JSR that is now standard in Java EE.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment de facto standard web framework for Java EE is [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org/). And plugin for eclipse can be found [here](http://www.eclipse-plugins.info/eclipse/plugin_details.jsp?id=506)